# Type mismatch using worksheet to clear cells

Tags: excel, worksheet, type-mismatch, vba

Can anyone tell me why the following VBA code gives me a Type mismatch in Excel?

```
Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Set mySheet = Worksheets("BOSS List")
Worksheets(mySheet).Cells.Clear
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mySheet` is a worksheet object no need to wrap it in `Worksheets()`:

```
Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Set mySheet = Worksheets("BOSS List")
mySheet.Cells.Clear
```

Answer (score 2):

You have already created a worksheet object called `mySheet`, you just need to make direct reference to it:

```
mySheet.Cells.Clear
```